# Wordpress - CRUD operation from the front end

Tags: wordpress, crud, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I'm in a bit of crux here. I have this application designed that basically allows users to enter info, create an entry, etc. etc. all the usual CRUD operations from the front end only. No user should ever have to mess around with the admin page.

When this was designed, I was thinking of using the standard way of just using JavaScript to grab all the necessary info, put it into a JSON object, and send that back to the SQL database.

However, there are a few issues with this. I'm not sure how to hook up javascript code to a button in wordpress that will fetch the entered info and upload this to wordpress SQL database, and then later retrieve this information.

I've seen lots of plugins, for instance, wpdataaccess, which is create in terms of creating an SQL database and such, but it doesn't really have much functionality for a customizable CRUD front-end. There are shortcodes, which are about the closest that you can come to this.

But ideally I'd like to somehow just have a button with JavaScript code that says like ok grab the info from each of the fields and upload it to the SQL database.

Is this only possible with a custom-coded plugin? Or do plugins for this already exist? Or do I even need a plugin?

Really any help would be appreciated here.

Also, you're probably wondering why I'm using wordpress... I don't really have an option here - I've got a raspberry pi OS that was built on top of WordPress so I sort of have to stick with it.

Thank you so much

Comment: If i got this right you just need some very small plugin (in the easiest form) to handle some ajax call to the wp core. It's quite easy to use AJAX in wordpress, you can find info here (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Remember that wp plugin can also be just a single file in your wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/plugin.php

Comment: cool thanks for the advice here, for now I just ended up using gravity forms and gravity view and if I ever need to customize more will perhaps look into making some plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this. Use the plugin gravity forms to have users enter their data. Then, you can display the data back with another plugin, gravity view.